# Backwards compatibility: Moving a module into a subpackage

Tags: python, package, python-import, backwards-compatibility

Lets say I have a Python package with this structure:

```
project
 +---> module1.py
 +---> module2.py
 +---> module3.py
```

Now, I decide to group these into subpackages:

```
project
 +---> topic1
   +---> module1.py
   +---> module2.py
 +---> topic2
   +---> module3.py
```

Let's further assume there are a lot of users in other projects (that I don't want to update/email/break their code without knowing) that use the following:

```
from project.module1 import AwesomeClass
```

This wouldn't work with the new design anymore.

What I can do is:

```
project
 +---> module1.py
 +---> topic1
   +---> module1.py
   +---> module2.py
 +---> topic2
   +---> module3.py
```

and the file `project/module1.py` contains only one line

```
# For backwards compatability
from project.topic1.module1 import AwesomeClass
```

This is not very pretty though and is kind of the opposite of refactoring.

Is there something that you could put in `__init__.py` to make it work, or some other hack to link it to it's old place without being so visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think

```
# For backwards compatability
from project.topic1.module1 import AwesomeClass
```

is the only sensible solution.